# how to combine data from different tables with different metadata into csv

Tags: sql, pandas

I have below tables in SQL. type is always in 2nd position for all my tables.

```
ID   type    Col1   Col2   Col3  
1    table1  AAA    BRYA   123   
2    table1  BBB    QAA    234   


ID   type     Col1   Col4  
1    table2   CCCC   VVV   
2    table2   BBC    QQQ   


ID   type    Col1   Col3   Col4  
1    table3  SSS    MMM    456   
2    table3  III    PPP    678
```

I have to put all these together in a stored proc . Next step is to calll this stored proc in pandas and populate all the data in one csv without headers.

These do not have same columns but I need to have all them (all tables data) in same csv file.
I tried of UNION ALL to concatenate the tables, but for this I need to have same columns across all the tables which is not an option.

I need csv in below format(Just append the data from different tables and populate it in csv).

```
1,table1,AAA,BRYA,123   
2,table1,BBB,QAA,234 
1,table2,CCCC,VVV   
2,table2,BBC,QQQ
1,table3,SSS,MMM,456   
2,table3,III,PPP,678
```

how do i write a code in stored proc to append the data in above format and export it into csv?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `UNION ALL` all three tables, when you want to join the tables vertically.

Missing column you add simply a `NULL` at the missng position because for `UNION` you need always the same amount of cpolumns

```
SELECT ID,   type,    Col1,  Col2 ,  Col3,   NULL   FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID ,  type,    Col1,  NULL  , NULL ,  Col4    FROM table2
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID,   type,    Col1 , NULL,   Col3,   Col4  FROM table3
```